# Error installing pandas on lambda AWS using serverless framework

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy a AWS lambda function called `transform_load` that imports pandas  using the serverless framework. I am using the requirements plugin to zip the requirements so that I won't run into memory issues.

When testing the function I am getting the error below. The python and numpy versions are correct.
The requirements are added through `pip freeze` from local env. In the serverless.yml I added the following:

```
custom:
  .....
  # Zip the python requirements due to AWS lambda memory restrictions.
  pythonRequirements:
    zip: true
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

That being said, I am not sure as well what is a good strategy on dealing with large libraries be it pandas or scikit on an AWS Lambda.

Thanks!

````
[ERROR] ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from "/var/lang/bin/python3.7"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.18.5"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/serverless_sdk/__init__.py", line 134, in wrapped_handler
    return user_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/s_transform_load.py", line 24, in error_handler
    raise e
  File "/var/task/s_transform_load.py", line 19, in <module>
    user_handler = serverless_sdk.get_user_handler('transform.transform_load')
  File "/var/task/serverless_sdk/__init__.py", line 56, in get_user_handler
    user_module = import_module(user_module_name)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/transform.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/tmp/sls-py-req/pandas/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)```
````

Comment: We're likely going to need more information than this. Can you share what you're doing to install the libraries, for example?

Comment: I have a local env setup, so I did pip freeze to a requirements file. In the serverless.yml file, I added  `serverless-python-requirements` under plugins and added PythonRequirements under custom with zip set to True. I am adding these in the original question as well.

Comment: Did you follow this tutorial? https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

Comment: Adding the `DockerizePip: non-linux` seemed to have solve the issue of the import. Thanks!